# How to initialise a ViewVC commit database on Debian?

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, svn, viewvc

I'm in the process of trying to move a [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) setup (along with Subversion repositories) from one server to another.

I have already created an empty "ViewVC" MySQL database and a database user to access it.

The command

```
/usr/lib/viewvc/svndbadmin -v rebuild /path/to/repo
```

still fails, apparently because the the database is not initialised properly (I was hoping "rebuild" would do that for me).

According to the [INSTALL](http://viewvc.tigris.org/source/browse/*checkout*/viewvc/trunk/INSTALL) file, one should probably use the `<VIEWVC_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY>/bin/make-database` script for this. However, the Debian ViewVC packages do not contain such a file! These are the packages I have installed:

```
$  dpkg -l|grep viewvc
ii  viewvc                1.0.5-0.2  view CVS/SVN repositories via HTTP
ii  viewvc-query          1.0.5-0.2  utility to query CVS commit database
```

My question is, **how are you actually supposed to set up a ViewVC commit database on Debian**? Google and ViewVC FAQ didn't seem very helpful with this, so I thought I'd give Server Fault a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, `/usr/lib/viewvc/make-database` script *is* included, in the `viewvc-query` package. Silly of me to miss that one (or I'm just too tired today).

So it's a simple matter of:

```
 sudo /usr/lib/viewvc/make-database
```

...which will prompt you for  MySQL username, password and database name. (Note that this clears all commit data if a ViewVC database with that name already existed.)

After this, `sudo /usr/lib/viewvc/svndbadmin -v rebuild /path/to/repo` works nicely.

Thanks and sorry.